# Расстановка знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

"Еж — птица гордая: не пнешь, не полетит" — правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все-таки думаю, запятая здесь неуместна, а нужно два тире: 
*Еж — птица гордая: не пнешь — не полетит* (между частями предложения "не пнешь" и "не полетит" подчиненная связь).

Или первое тире не ставить (так лучше): 
*Еж птица гордая: не пнешь — не полетит*.

А двоеточие очень даже к месту здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Бедный ёжик...
Один знак надо заменить. Вместо запятой необходимо тире в части "не пнёшь - не полетит", так как эта часть представляет собой сложное бессоюзное предложение, в котором первая часть (не пнёшь) выражает условие того, о чём говорится во второй (не полетит). А при таком раскладе ставится только тире.